# What does the Poisson bracket actually mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

### Context (pg-321):

We have a manifold with an anti symmetric metric tensor/sympletic form $S$ with components in a basis $S_{ab}$ satisfying the property that

$$dS=0$$

Where $d$ is the exterior derivative.

The components of the inverse of metric tensor  in the same basis is given as $S^{ab}$

---

### Question :

In page-322 , the following equation is given as the Poisson bracket of two scalar field:

$$ \{\Phi, \Psi \} = - \frac12 S^{ab} \nabla_a \Phi \nabla_b \Psi$$

What does the above expression mean actually? Could perhaps a picture be provided to explain it?

Comment: You missed a subscript and what is $S_{ab}$?

Comment: Anti symmetric metric tensor on the sympletic manifold

Comment: I tried to edit it @BinxuWang王彬旭 hopefully it is clear now

Comment: Thansk! looks much clearer now

Comment: It’s worth starting with the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket

Comment: You have not mentioned any Jacobi identity in your question. Also, what do you mean by antisymmetric mectric tensor? Do you mean symplectic form?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment. I had started writing this question with one intent and as I wrote it, I realize that I didn't even understand what the bracket meant @J.V.Gaiter